# CMake compile glsl shaders

Tags: cmake, glsl, vulkan

I am adapting Sascha Willems' [Vulkan Samples](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan) to compile shaders when ever i build the program. I know this question has been asked a lot but none of the solutions I found worked for me.

Here is my code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(Test)

set( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/shaders)

set(SHADER_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/shaders)
file(GLOB SHADERS ${SHADER_DIR}/*.vert ${SHADER_DIR}/*.frag ${SHADER_DIR}/*.comp ${SHADER_DIR}/*.geom ${SHADER_DIR}/*.tesc ${SHADER_DIR}/*.tese ${SHADER_DIR}/*.mesh ${SHADER_DIR}/*.task ${SHADER_DIR}/*.rgen ${SHADER_DIR}/*.rchit ${SHADER_DIR}/*.rmiss)

file(GLOB SPV_SHADERS ${SHADER_DIR}/*.spv)

find_package(Vulkan)

foreach(SHADER IN LISTS SHADERS)
    get_filename_component(FILENAME ${SHADER} NAME)
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${SHADER_DIR}/shaders/${FILENAME}.spv
        COMMAND ${Vulkan_GLSLC_EXECUTABLE} ${SHADER} -o ${SHADER_DIR}/shaders/${FILENAME}.spv
        DEPENDS ${SHADER}
        COMMENT "Compiling ${FILENAME}")
endForeach()

add_custom_target(shaders ALL DEPENDS ${SPV_SHADERS})

add_executable(Test main.cpp ${SHADERS})
add_dependencies(Test shaders)
```

[Edit]: CMake seems to skip the foreach loop am I using it correctly?

[Edit2]: Now the loop works but the shaders are still not compiling

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: The shaders doesn't compile. CMake acts as if it has nothing to do.

Comment: Try putting `message(...)` debug prints to check whether the loop behaves as you expect it to.

Comment: I've done it and I think CMake just skip the loop.

Answer (score 1):

After searching a bit, I deleted `file(GLOB SPV_SHADERS ${SHADER_DIR}/*.spv)` and replaced it with `list(APPEND SPV_SHADERS ${ASSETS_DIR}/shaders/${FILENAME}.spv)`

It would look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(Test)

set( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/shaders)

set(SHADER_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/shaders)
file(GLOB SHADERS ${SHADER_DIR}/*.vert ${SHADER_DIR}/*.frag ${SHADER_DIR}/*.comp ${SHADER_DIR}/*.geom ${SHADER_DIR}/*.tesc ${SHADER_DIR}/*.tese ${SHADER_DIR}/*.mesh ${SHADER_DIR}/*.task ${SHADER_DIR}/*.rgen ${SHADER_DIR}/*.rchit ${SHADER_DIR}/*.rmiss)

find_package(Vulkan)

foreach(SHADER IN LISTS SHADERS)
    get_filename_component(FILENAME ${SHADER} NAME)
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${SHADER_DIR}/shaders/${FILENAME}.spv
        COMMAND ${Vulkan_GLSLC_EXECUTABLE} ${SHADER} -o ${SHADER_DIR}/shaders/${FILENAME}.spv
        DEPENDS ${SHADER}
        COMMENT "Compiling ${FILENAME}")
list(APPENDS SPV_SHADERS ${SHADER_DIR}/shaders/${FILENAME}.spv)
endForeach()

add_custom_target(shaders ALL DEPENDS ${SPV_SHADERS})

add_executable(Test main.cpp ${SHADERS})
add_dependencies(Test shaders)
```